# How to assign a worksheet variable using a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with a list of report data sources, including server name, table, fields, groupby etc...  I can then select the entries I wish to refresh via  Slicer and hit REFFRESH.
One column has the name of the table where the data should be put, just a basic string.  How can I assign that to a worksheet variable.

I get TYPE MISMATCH when using the following.  x is just part of a loop that checks each row in the table to see if it is selected.

```
dim oLo As ListObject, cTab As Worksheet
Set cTab = wb.Sheets(oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 10))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made any assignment to your `oLo` object variable. If that variable is `Nothing`, you can expect an error here...

Comment: The cell reference is fine, I've already found the solution. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Took me 5 minutes to write the question, then I get a flash of inspiration.  I just needed to add a `"" &` and `& ""` before/after the variable/cell reference.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("ADMIN")
Set oLo = ws.ListObjects(1)    

For x = 1 To rCNT
    'Trigger update for each visible row
    If oLo.DataBodyRange.Rows(x).Hidden = False Then
        cFields = oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 7)
        cTable = oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 6)
        cCriteria = oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 8)
        cGroup = oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 9)
        Set cTab = wb.Sheets(oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 10).Value)
        Set cRng = cTab.Range(oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 11))
        ' - Call to function that refreshes the data
        ' - TBC
        ' - -------------------------------------
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: Really? That doesn't seem like it would help at all... Cool solution though! What happens if you just do `"" & oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 10)` and leave off the last concat? My bet is that it's forcing the value to a string which makes the Sheets object happy.

Comment: Rather than using the `""` you could *probably* just do `oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x,10).Value` or `Cstr(oLo.DataBodyRange.Cells(x,10).Value`.

Comment: This look like a case of [Type Inference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx) rather than the empty string concatenation doing anything magical - in which case simply wrapping the original statement in `CStr()` to cast to a string would do the same thing.

Comment: @DavidZemens You are correct. Simply using `.Value` would fix this. And of course it's good practice to **always** be explicit like that. ;)

Comment: Looks like you were both right and it is much tidier. Thnx